# Why is the number of accrued days equal to one on coupon dates for NL/365?

Tags: bond, bloomberg, daycounting, accrued-interest

Accrued day should be zero on coupon dates. This is true for all day count conventions. However, I found that Bloomberg returns 1 accrued day on coupon dates only for NL/365 day count.

*Bond example:*

- ID Number:EK6400528
- Financial instrument global: BBG007NPRMY8
- Name: ZHENGZHOU MOUZHONG DEVEL
- Effective: 12/11/2014
- Maturity: 12/11/2021
- Frequency: Annual

So, for example, on the coupon date 12/11/2018 Bloomberg returns accrued days as 1.

Comment: Is 12/11/2018 the settlement date?

Comment: @Magicisinthechain Yes, I performed calculation for that settlement date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to the description page of this bond it says under the calculation type:

> Day count is NL/365 for Shanghai or Shenzhen listed securities and ACT/ACT for all others.
>   For Shanghai or Shenzhen listed bonds accrued interest is calculated
>   inclusive of both the settlement and previous coupon. Note this will
>   result in one day of interest for settlement on a payment date.

So this bond appears to follow an 'extra-day' accrued convention.

Comment: Tnx, this explains everything. I wasn't looking at the additional description believing that all conventions are standardize on global level.